# How do I access delegation.parent from delegation.child?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

I took this example code from odoo documentation:

```
class Child0(models.Model):
    _name = 'delegation.child0'

    field_0 = fields.Integer()

class Child1(models.Model):
    _name = 'delegation.child1'

    field_1 = fields.Integer()

class Delegating(models.Model):
    _name = 'delegation.parent'

    _inherits = {
        'delegation.child0': 'child0_id',
        'delegation.child1': 'child1_id',
    }

    child0_id = fields.Many2one('delegation.child0', required=True, ondelete='cascade')
    child1_id = fields.Many2one('delegation.child1', required=True, ondelete='cascade')
    example_field = fields.Char('Example Field')
```

Can I access the parent's `example_field` from the child easily? How?